# Javascript 'undefined' error, when trying to get values from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get values from an array on my database, however everytime I run the code it says that the value is 'undefined'. But it return the right values when I use document.write, why is that? Here is the code that returns 'undefined':

```
 $.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {

        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            //janela de informação de cada marcador


            //console.log(item);
            var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                // iterar todas as ocorrencias para tirar delas as imagens
                item.listaOcorrencias.forEach(function (ocorrencia, o) {
                    ocorrencias.azimute
                });

                +'<p> Latitude: </p>'

            var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], { icon: ignicao })
                .bindPopup(infowindow)
                .on('click', onClick)
                .addTo(map);




            $('#json map').append(marker);


        }); 
    });
```

The model that I refer to (Ignicoes) has a property that is a list:

```
  public class Ignicoes
{

    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();

    }

    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }

}
```

listaOcorrencias is what I'm trying to access on my Index.

[image]

When I use document.write the map doesn't appear, but the right value is returned 
[image]

Comment: need more details or code snippets? may be when you accessing that data asynchronously that is not ready yet.

Comment: I added more code, so it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 var something;
 item.listaOcorrencias.forEach(function (ocorrencia, o) {
                something = ocorrencias.azimute;
                });
var infowindow = '<div id="content" style="hight:700px; width:500px">' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p><b>Avaliação da Ocorrência:</b></p>' +
                // iterar todas as ocorrencias para tirar delas as imagens
               something

                +'<p> Latitude: </p>'
```